# Changing overall scale of a graph in manim

Tags: manim

How do you change the overall scale of a graph in manim?

```
    self.graph_origin = 1 * RIGHT + 0.3 * DOWN
    self.setup_axes(animate = True)


    self.LINE = lambda x :  2 * x + 1
    LINE = self.get_graph(self.LINE, y_min = -3, y_max =3,  x_min = -2, x_max = 1.5, graph_origin = ORIGIN )
```

If I use

```
 self.get_graph(scale = 0.5)
```

This does not scale the axes.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, and you didn't specify which version of manim you use. In the current version of manim community, you could do something like this:

```
ax = Axes(
         x_range=[0, 10], y_range=[0, 100, 10]
        )
labels = ax.get_axis_labels(x_label="x", y_label="f(x)")

def func(x):
    return 2 * (x - 5) ** 2

graph = ax.plot(func, color=MAROON)

plot_group = VGroup(ax, labels, graph).scale(0.5)

self.add(plot_group)
self.wait(2)
```

Checkout [Plotting with Manim](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/examples.html#plotting-with-manim) and [VGroup](https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.types.vectorized_mobject.VGroup.html?highlight=vgroup).

You could also animate the scaling if you like:

```
self.play(plot_group.animate.scale(0.5))
```